# Flutter button hint text not showing

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using the package multi_select_flutter, that displays a dropdown better than the native flutter option. However, the hint text is not showing - it was showing up until yesterday, and then disappeared, and I am not sure why this is happening. Did anyone else have the same issue? Here is my code

```
MultiSelectBottomSheetField(
                      initialChildSize: 0.4,
                      listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
                      searchable: true,
                      selectedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 31, 31, 31),
                      searchHint: 'Biceps',
                      confirmText:
                          Text('SAVE', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      selectedItemsTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      buttonText: Text("Muscles used",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                          )),
                      buttonIcon:
                          Icon(Icons.arrow_downward, color: Colors.white),
                      barrierColor:
                          Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 43, 43).withOpacity(.7),
                      title: Text("Muscles  (Scroll down for more)"),
                      items: _options,
                      onConfirm: (values) {
                        selectedOptions = values;
                      },
                      initialValue: selectedOptions,
                      chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                        onTap: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedOptions.remove(value);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: One possibility is that your hintText is not visible because it is the same color as the background. You can try changing the hintStyle to a different color or use a labelText instead.

Another possibility is that your buttonText is overlapping with your hintText. You can try adjusting the buttonText size or position or use a labelText instead.

Comment: Thanks samgi for your response! I change the color to no avail, and also tried using labelText (which isn't supported). I don't know why it isn't working and am very frustrated. Thanks again for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and there is a bug in MultiSelectBottomSheetField, when you define textStyle for buttonText it doesn't show it, however, you needs to remove textStyle that you have defined for buttonText and it will show it.

Comment: Amin I just tried that and replaced that line with "buttonText: Text("Muscles used")," but unfortunately that still doesn't work. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: I think its due to your theme text color is white(as same as background), i mean your material app text theme is set to white or something like that

Comment: It wasn't that - I commented out a line in the source files and had to un comment it out. Thanks for your help though! marked it as accepted